# Trouble accessing column value rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-console

I'm trying to access the integer stored in a column called totalVotes in my UserVotes table but keep getting a No Method Error

I have been trying to debug from the console:

```
1.9.3-p327 :006 > uservote = UserVote.where("soundcloud_id = 68061927")
  UserVote Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "user_votes".* FROM "user_votes" WHERE (soundcloud_id = 68061927)
 => [#<UserVote id: 5, user_id: "1", party_profile_id: "1", soundcloud_id: "68061927", totalVotes: 0, created_at: "2013-02-19 04:57:58", updated_at: "2013-02-19 04:57:58">]
```

Good so far...

```
1.9.3-p327 :007 > uservote.totalVotes
NoMethodError: undefined method `totalVotes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007febb49ab350>
```

Then it breaks and I'm not sure why. What is the best way for me to access the totalVotes value?

Comment: Are you sure the column is not called total_votes?  The convention in Rails is to use "_" instead of camel case.

Comment: I set the column to be called totalVotes

Comment: class UserVote < Activerecord::Base
  alias_attribute :totalVotes, :total_votes
end
Have you used like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue is you're calling `.totalVotes` to an AR Relation.  call `.first` first then you should have no problem.

```
>> uservote = UserVote.where("soundcloud_id = 68061927").first
>> uservote.totalVotes
```